# How can i round float to nearest whole number and then convert into double in JAVA?

Tags: java, rounding

**I have a float value**

```
float myValue=5.1824203;
```

- How can i round float to nearest whole number and then convert into
  double?
- What is the best method to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double myRoundedDoubleValue = Math.round(myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
public static void main(String arguments[]) {
    float myValue=5.1824203f;
    int rounded = Math.round(myValue);
    System.out.println("as int: " + rounded);
    float floated = (float) rounded;
    System.out.println("as float: " + floated);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
as int: 5
as float: 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float myValue=5.1824203f;
double rounded = Math.round(myValue);
```

Please also note the difference in the float myValue initialization.